# java : sort and delete or refresh data make exception in jtable

Tags: java, sorting, jtable, refresh

please excute this code with java, and then..

`button pattern1 -> button pattern2 -> table sort with any columns. -> 
button delete -> exception.`

Why exception occured?

here's code.

please help me..

## ===============================================

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    private DefaultTableModel modelTest = new DefaultTableModel();
    private JTable tableTest = new JTable(modelTest);
    private JScrollPane paneTest = new JScrollPane(tableTest);

    private JButton button1 = new JButton("pattern1");
    private JButton button2 = new JButton("pattern2");
    private JButton button3 = new JButton("delete");

    private void compInit() {
        paneTest.setBounds(0, 0, 778, 300);
        button1.setBounds(250, 320, 80, 20);
        button2.setBounds(450, 320, 80, 20);
        button3.setBounds(300, 400, 80, 20);

        DefaultTableModel tmp = modelTest;

        tmp.addColumn("  ");
        tmp.addColumn("col1");
        tmp.addColumn("col2");
        tmp.addColumn("col3");
        tmp.addColumn("col4");
        tmp.addColumn("col5");
        tmp.addColumn("col6");
        tmp.addColumn("col7");

        try {
            tableTest.setDefaultRenderer(Class.forName("java.lang.String"), new DefaultTableCellRenderer());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tableTest.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        tableTest.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        tableTest.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(20);
        tableTest.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(45);
        tableTest.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(110);
        tableTest.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(60);
        tableTest.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(100);
        tableTest.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(227);
        tableTest.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(100);
        tableTest.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(100);
        tableTest.getTableHeader().setForeground(new Color(105, 105, 105));

        this.add(button1);
        this.add(button2);
        this.add(button3);
        this.add(paneTest);
    }

    private void pattern1() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Vector rowData = new Vector<>();
            rowData.add(false);
            rowData.add(i + 1);
            rowData.add("a : " + i);
            rowData.add("b : " + i);
            rowData.add("c : " + i);
            rowData.add("d : " + i);
            rowData.add("e : " + i);
            rowData.add("f : " + i);
            modelTest.addRow(rowData);
        }
    }

    private void pattern2() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Vector rowData = new Vector<>();
            rowData.add(false);
            rowData.add(i + 1);
            rowData.add("z : " + i);
            rowData.add("y : " + i);
            rowData.add("x : " + i);
            rowData.add("w : " + i);
            rowData.add("v : " + i);
            rowData.add("u : " + i);
            modelTest.addRow(rowData);
        }
    }

    private void delete() {
        DefaultTableModel tmp = modelTest;
        tmp.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
        tableTest.repaint();
    }


    private void eventInit() {
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pattern1();
            }
        });
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pattern2();
            }
        });
        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                delete();
            }
        });
    }

    public Test() {
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.compInit();
        this.eventInit();
        this.setSize(778, 500);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in *delete()* method. *JTable* is designed using *MVC* pattern, so after removing all rows in *Model*, you should notify *View* about that. So correct version of *delete()* method will be:

```
private void delete() {
    DefaultTableModel tmp = modelTest;
    tmp.getDataVector().removeAllElements();

    modelTest.fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delele the rows you should go through the model's method:

instead of

```
tmp.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
```

do it like this:

```
while (modelTest.getRowCount() > 0){
    modelTest.removeRow(0);
}
```